# What class is directly implementing ListIterator?

Tags: java

What class actually implements the interface `ListIterator`? I'm studying the Collections API.. and it would seem as though the actual method that returns a `ListIterator` within the `List` implementation classes is directly specified in `List` itself.

The `ListIterator` interface specifies that actual methods that you would use to manipulate the iterator.. but I am having trouble finding the actual class that implements this.

What class actually -implements- the interface `ListIterator` that allows the method in the `List` classes to work?

I'm sure there has to be an implementation class because calling `listIterator()` itself surely can not return an Interface, there must be something instantiated.

Comment: Are you aware of private inner classes? Or, for example, anonymous classes?

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg Not yet. I'm assuming this is the source of my confusion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't instantiate an `interface`, but you can always create "invisible" `private class`, which is satisfying `interface`, but user can't directly see it. For example, `LinkedList` defines `listIterator` as:

```
public ListIterator<E> listIterator(int index) {
    checkPositionIndex(index);
    return new ListItr(index);
}

private class ListItr implements ListIterator<E> {
    private Node<E> lastReturned;
    private Node<E> next;
    private int nextIndex;
    private int expectedModCount = modCount;

    ListItr(int index) {
        // assert isPositionIndex(index);
        next = (index == size) ? null : node(index);
        nextIndex = index;
    }

    // much more
}
```

This behavior have it's final form in lambdas, in which you won't have any  temptation for looking in sources of the passed class.

Answer (score 2):

Use the source luke... use the source.

from the source of `ArrayList` in JDK 8 (1.8.0_45)

```
public ListIterator<E> listIterator() {
    return new ListItr(0);
}

// then line 905
/**
 * An optimized version of AbstractList.ListItr
 */
private class ListItr extends Itr implements ListIterator<E> {
    ListItr(int index) {
        super();
        cursor = index;
    }
// etc
```

So the `ListIterator` returned by `ArrayList` is a private inner class that implements the interface `ListIterator`.

Answer (score -1):

ListIterator adds functionality for iterating lists [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html).
This is an usage example:

`List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
 ListIterator<String> it = l.listIterator();
 it.next() ...`